# Phonegap Android datepicker

Tags: java, android, cordova, backbone.js, datepicker

I am building an Android application using Phonegap and I found [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker) which I decided to use for my datepicker fields. I follow the instructions, but I have trouble running that.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<label for="schedule_start">Start date</label>
<input type="text" class="nativedatepicker" id="schedule_start" name="schedule[start_date]" value="{{start_date}}" required />
```

JS (I'm using Backbone.js)

```
FormView.prototype.defaultEvents = {
'focus .nativedatepicker': 'focusDatepicker'
};

// call when input focused

FormView.prototype.focusDatepicker = function(e) {
var currentField = $(this);
var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();

if(typeof myNewDate === "number"){ myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate); }

// Same handling for iPhone and Android
window.plugins.datePicker.show({
  date : myNewDate,
    mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
    allowOldDates : true
  }, function(returnDate) {
    var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
    currentField.val(newDate.toString("YYYY-MM-DD"));

    // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
    currentField.blur();
  });
};
```

I've added the `datePickerPlugin.js` to `/assets/www/js/` and the `DatePickerPlugin.java` to `/src/com/phonegap/plugin/` after creating the `com.phonegap.plugin` package.

I think I might have some problem invoking the datePickerPlugin.js, since I don't get the alert I put in the file, but I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you included the datepickerplugin.js file in your index.html file with correct path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both for the hint to look at my paths. It appears I haven't included my Cordova library file properly. After I did, it all worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I resolved it by including the datePickerPlugin.js file after cordova.js.